# How to reorder tabs in Kate?

Tags: ubuntu, tabs, ordering, kate

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Kate Version 15.12.3 through the official Apt repositories. For some reason now I am unable to reorder tabs.

[image: screenshot of kate tabs]

I may be mistaken, but I could have sworn that all I needed to do was drag and drop the tabs like it works in any web browser, but I can't get the tabs to reorder without closing the documents and reopening them in the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

I also have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Kate version: 15.12.3. I'm unable to re order tabs.

Searching on reddit I found [Kate: Is there a way to change the order of the tabs?](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/3eabnl/kate_is_there_a_way_to_change_the_order_of_the/)

Conclusion:
It was partially enabled in Kate 4 (with a plugin). Kate 5 doesn't have it anymore, but you are free to submit a patch to develop the feature.

If only this was an easy task.